# How to Move a production WordPress site to local environment

Tags: plugins, backup, local-installation

I need to know which tool that will make an exact duplicate of databases, plugins and everything to my local.

free or paying.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to have a local webserver with php and mysql to run the site locally (e.g. [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html)). Then you have to download all your WordPress files and copy them into the source folder of your local webserver (e.g. xampp/htdocs). The next step is to copy your database. To do this, you have to export it from your website and import it on your local environment. At last you have to edit your wp-config.php. Update the database configuration (DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST) and add the following two lines before `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */`:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localurl' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localurl' );
```

If you need further information (e.g. how to download the files, how to export/import the database) i need more information about your system (e.g. how do you access your site and database).

Comment: do these steps guarantee that the plugins won't have errors on my local?

Comment: You can never gice a 100% warranty but normally everything should work correctly. I'm using the same way on my WordPress installations